# Extracting every nth m items from a list

Tags: python

What's the most efficient way of extracting every nth m items from a list. So if I have:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...]
```

I would like every 3rd 2 items, starting from the first index:

```
[1,2,7,8,13,14,...]
```

Comment: l[start:stop:step], so l[0::3]

Comment: @MegaIng They want every 3rd pair, not every 3rd element.

Comment: Show us your current method and we'll tell if it's efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `%` operator for that:

```
[val for i, val in enumerate(lst) if i % 6 < 2]
```

In general, if you want to extract every *n*<sup>th</sup> *m* values, then:

```
[val for i, val in enumerate(lst) if i % (n*m) < m]
```

Comment: \‾ (`-` )  - thank you!!
I was trying something similar, so you using your example I was trying:
[x for x in lst if x%6<4]
but that didn't work.
How can we generalize your solution to every nth, m items? So would be great to have something on the lines of
[val for i, val in enumerate(lst) if i % m < n]
Trying now, will post the solution if I could figure it out!

Comment: For *n*th of *m* if would be `i % (n*m) < m`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
s = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
new_s = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(zip(s, range(len(s))), key=lambda x:x[-1]%6 == 0 or (x[-1]-1)%6 == 0)]
final_data = list(itertools.chain(*[map(lambda x:x[0], b) for a, b in new_s if a]))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
data=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]

for i in range(0,len(data),6):
    print(data[i:i+2])
```

output:

```
[1, 2]
[7, 8]
[13, 14]
```